# Clarity on last blank row

Tags: excel, vba

So this might be a stupid question, but just want to ask for clarity because the internet has confused me

If i set a dimension to this, for example

```
x = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Will this give me the last row of Column A or the last row of the whole spreadsheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Column A, to get a different column change ```1``` to whatever column you want to use.

Comment: A simple test would have told you the answer probably a bit quicker =)

Comment: Im so confused ahah, can someone help

Comment: currently its giving me the last row of the whole sheet and i dont know why @JvdV

Comment: `Cells` is an implicit reference to `ActiveSheet` so maybe that's where your problem lays more. Be *explicit*.

Comment: Try qualifying your `Cell` object and tell it which worksheet to point at, something like `x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Also you can use a column by letter, sometimes easier when dealing with high-numbered columns (e.g. `x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Also, if you have formulae in that column, even though they look invisible they still count towards the row count. It's either the wrong sheet you're pointing at or there are formulae in the column past the last visible row.

Comment: Yeah I actually had invisible text, whoops @jamheadart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give you the row number of the last occupied cell in column **A** of the active worksheet:

```
Sub EndConfusion()
    Dim x As Long
    x = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

[image]

*(if this is not what you are seeing, it may be that the wrong sheet is active?)*